# Using Python to write a loop that goes through JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops

I have a JSON record but I can't use any JSON commands or libraries, I have to use python, I'm stuck ont his part that says "write a loop to go through the JSON record and print all the product numbers(product_id) on the order. You also need to print the quantity for each line item and the total number of items in the whole order". Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
## JSON Record

order_info =
     {
     "order":"4321",
     "created_at":"2018-03-01 00:00:00",
     "customer_id":"1008",
     "line_items":
         [                       #line item record begins
             {                   #first line item 
             "product_id":"5008798",
             "price":"5.99",
             "quantity":"1",
             "tax_lines":
                 [               #tax line record begins
                     {           #first line tax item
                     "price":"5.99",
                     "rate":"0.06",
                     "title":"State Tax"
                     },
                     {
                     "price":"1.99",
                     "rate":"0.01",
                     "title":"City Tax"
                     },
                     {
                     "price":"12.99",
                     "rate":"1.06",
                     "title":"County Tax"
                     }
                  ]                  #tax line record ends
              },
             {
             "product_id":"A36",
             "price":"7.99",
             "quantity":"2",
             "tax_lines":
             [                   #tax line record begins
                 {
                 "price":"14.98"
                 "rate":"2.01",
                 "title":"City Tax"
            
                 }
            ]               #tax line record ends
         }
     }
```

Comment: That looks like a python `dict` (apart from a missing `]`). Do you have a `dict` or is that intended to be a string?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your desired output so we can help you better